# How to update a screen from another screen, both in different python file with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

In the case of a large project requiring several screens, I would have to put each screen in a python file and then call them in a single main.py file. But how do you change an element on one screen from another screen? In this example, if the login screen is in a login.py file and the home screen is in a home.py file, how do you change the Label in the home.py screen from the login.py screen?

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from login import LoginScreen
from home import HomeScreen

Builder.load_string(
"""
<ManagerScreen>:
    Screen:
        id: login
        name: 'login'
    MDScreen:
        id: register
        name: 'register'
    Screen:
        id: home
        name: 'home'

""" )

class ManagerScreen(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManagerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.login.add_widget(LoginScreen())
        self.ids.home.add_widget(HomeScreen())


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ManagerScreen()
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

login.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import sqlite3
from loading import LoadImage

Builder.load_string(
"""
<LoginScreen>:
    MDCard:
        size_hint: .5, .4
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        MDTextField:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Nom d'utilisateur"
        MDTextField:
            id: pwd
            hint_text: "Mot de passe"
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Connexion'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
            on_press: root.log_in()
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Créez un compte si vous n'en avez pas!"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
            on_press: root.parent.parent.current = 'register'
"""
    )

#class HomeScreen(MDBoxLayout):
    #pass


class LoginScreen(MDRelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def log_in(self):

        home_screen = self.parent.manager.get_screen('home')
        home_screen.update()
        self.parent.parent.current = 'home'
```

home.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import sqlite3
from loading import LoadImage

Builder.load_string(
"""
#:import utils kivy.utils
<HomeScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: first.height
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: first
                text: "Ecran 1"
                on_press: sm.current = 'firstscreen'
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: first
                text: "Ecran 2"
                on_press: sm.current = 'secondscreen'
        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            Screen:
                id: firstscreen
                name: 'firstscreen'
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    MDCard:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        md_bg_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#3e55c9')
                        MDLabel:
                            id: lab
                            markup: True
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            id: buttontext
                            text: 'importer fichier'

            Screen:
                id: secondscreen
                name: 'secondscreen'

"""
    )


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        

    def update(self):
        self.ids.lab.text = "Bienvenu Monsieur"
```

Here's the mistake they tell me when I execute

File "D:\MON PROJET\my test kivy\base de donnee\login.py", line 45, in log_in
home_screen.update()
AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'update'

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

`self.parent.manager.get_screen('home')` is not the instance of `HomeScreen`, **`HomeScreen` is a child widget of it** since you add it with:

```
self.ids.home.add_widget(HomeScreen())
```

For example, if you do:

```
def log_in(self):
    home_screen = self.parent.manager.get_screen('home')
    home_screen.children[0].update()  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    self.parent.parent.current = 'home'
```

it will work.

However, instead of nesting `HomeScreen` inside another instance of `Screen`, you can simply do:

##### **`main.py`**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from login import LoginScreen
from home import HomeScreen

Builder.load_string(
"""
<ManagerScreen>:
    Screen:
        id: login
        name: 'login'
    MDScreen:
        id: register
        name: 'register'
    HomeScreen: # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        id: home
        name: 'home'

""" )

class ManagerScreen(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManagerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.login.add_widget(LoginScreen())
        # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ManagerScreen()
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

and you don't need to modify any of the other scripts.

Comment: Thanks man, it works well. You're amazing. Please, can you be a contact for me who I can write to if I get stuck? If so, can I get a whatsapp or a snap or an email?